# Flutter type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

what I want to do is to pull some data from the docs where the logged in user is email from the collection named Repair. I created a function for this. But I'm getting the - type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' - error.

```dart
getCustomerRepairLog() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    var _repairLogs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Repair').get();
    for (var eleman in _repairLogs.docs) {
      if (eleman.data()['email']! == user.email) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("$eleman.data()['description']"),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    return Text('Loading');
  }
```

I want to use it as getCustomerRepairLog() in Column. Can you help me?

Comment: use FutureBuilder for dealing with future

Comment: @MunsifAli The FutureBuilder structure was confusing to me. I don't know how to use it. Are there any resources you can recommend?

Comment: first of all i would recommend the official documentation and you can watch this video also https://youtu.be/Rlf5q2EGHzc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use FutureBuilder for future method.Create state variable to avoid recalling evrytime the state is build.

```dart
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!; //better do a null check 1st
late final _repairLogs = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Repair').get();
```

And your method will be like

```dart
  Widget getCustomerRepairLog() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _repairLogs,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Widget> items = [];
          final data = snapshot.data?.docs;
          if (data == null) return Text("got null");

          for (final eleman in data) {
            if (eleman.data()['email']! == user.email) {
              items.add(Text("${eleman.data()['description']}"));
            }
          }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
```

Find more about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: I'm getting an error in the _repairLogs.docs section in the for. I guess because async await is not used. How can I do about it?

Comment: Can you share the error massage

Comment: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

Comment: Oh, it will be `snapshot.data` now. Try `for (var eleman in snapshot.data) {` if it raise null issue, you can do a a null check

Comment: ok, I will update, need to null check

Comment: snapshot.data?.docs is getting error.
The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

Comment: are you using update version of cloud_firestore

Comment: I'm checking. one second

Comment: no, 3.4.9 version

Comment: well I am using `4.1.0`, that one should've work too.  can you recheck `future:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Repair').get(),` this format

Comment: I upgraded my version to 4.1.0. But I am still getting the same error. future I checked.

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. I cant see any issue  now.

Comment: I did flutter clean then flutter run. But I keep getting errors. Interesting :(

Comment: okay, builder: (context, snapshot) I Change builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) and problem fixed. Thank you :)